# How to render JSON on a frontend html page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display a JSON string on a HTML page. The JSON string looks like this:

```
{ 
       email: '111@11.com',
       username: '1111',
       roles: {},
       array: ['data','data'] },
     { 
       email: 'go@1.com',
       username: 'go',
       roles: {},
       array: [ 'c', 'c' ] } ]
```

The HTML is like this:

```
<div id="my_id">
    <h3>json.email1</h3>
    <div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>json.array1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
<h3>json.email2</h3>
    <div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>json.array2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
<h3>json.email3</h3>
    <div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>json.array3</p>
      </div>
    </div>     
  </div>
```

The HTML has to be automatically added to make sure all the JSON elements are populated in the HTML tags.What would be the easiest way to do this? Could someone please help me out?

HTML:

```
<div>
   <div id="people">
      <h3><a href="mailto:{{this.email}}">{{this.name}}</a></h3>
      <div>
         <div class="content">
            <p>This example simply sets a class attribute to the details and let's an
               external stylesheet toggle the collapsed state.
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script>
         var data = [
         { name: "Olga", age: 20, email: "aaa@example.com" },
         { name: "Peter", age: 30, email: "bbb@example.com" },
         { name: "Ivan", age: 15, email: "ccc@example.com" },
         ];
         var list = $("div#people").repeatable(); // declaring the repeatable
         list.value = data; // that's data population, sic!
      </script>
   </div>
</div>
```

HTML :

```
   <div class="people">
    <h3>Foe</h3>
    <div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>This example simply sets a class attribute to the details and let's an
        external stylesheet toggle the collapsed state.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The above code does not display the collapse structure. The moment the entire thing is wrapped into the div class=people, it does not work correctly(does not show the collapse ).

Comment: Why is this tagged `backbone`?

Comment: Removed the tag. I was using Backbone in this application but I dont think the issue is related to it.

Comment: And why is it tagged jade ?

Comment: I do not see where you initialize that collapsible() functionality.

It should look like  `var list = $("div.people").repeatable(); list.value = data; $("div.people").collapse({ ... options... });`

Comment: I didnt put that in the post for the clarity. If you just download the library and put an extra div to wrap it around the collapse does not work. The other ones where there is no div seems to work fine(collapse function)

Comment: Added a short example for demo.html:http://pastebin.com/AcPt3ecC

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular.js, is a library to make this kind of things. Is pretty simple:

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
<body ng-controller="mycontroller">
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
        <h3>{{ user.email }}</h3>
        <p>{{ user.username }}</p>
        <div ng-repeat="data in array">
             {{ data }}
        </div>
   </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
     var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
     app.controller = ('mycontroller', function($scope){
           $scope.users = {
                //your data here
           }
     });
</script>
<body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

While ago I've designed so called repeatable jQuery plugin: https://github.com/c-smile/repeatable

So if you have template (html fragment) like this:

```
<ul id="people">
    <li><a href="mailto:{{this.email}}">{{this.name}}</a> <b if="this.age > 18">18+</b> </li> 
    <li>No data available</li>
</ul>
```

and data

```
var data = [
       { name: "Olga", age: 20, email: "aaa@example.com" },
       { name: "Peter", age: 30, email: "bbb@example.com" },
       { name: "Ivan", age: 15, email: "ccc@example.com" },
    ];
```

Then to render list from that data you will do just this:

```
var list = $("ul#people").repeatable(); // declaring the repeatable
    list.value = data; // that's data population, sic!
```

Here is the [demo](http://terrainformatica.com/widgets.js/repeatable/repeatable-test.htm).

Comment: I am currently using https://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Collapse for the collpasible item in the list. Is it easy to integrate the two?

Comment: @user2578666 I do not see any problems, they should work together

Comment: The moment I wrap the entire structure into the div class=people it does not show the collapsible structure. Do you have any ideas ?